# Get current timestamp from specific date using UTC/GMT+0 as epoch ignoring local time zone epoch

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, epoch

I've tried a lot from this community but it seems like there's no hyper specific scenario for my case.

So basically I have a string in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`. I use date methods to adjust it and add time on the date to make it more specific. I want to convert it to timestamp while ignoring the client computer's current timezone (or using UTC timezone).

I have this code:

```
function getTimestampRange(sparams, eparams){

sparams = "2018-11-12", eparams = "2018-11-13"; //sample param values

const start = sparams.split("-");
const end = eparams.split("-");

const startDate = new Date(start[0], start[1] - 1, start[2]);
const endDate = new Date(end[0], end[1] - 1, end[2]);
endDate.setHours(23);
endDate.setMinutes(59);
endDate.setSeconds(59);

//startDate is 2018-11-12 00:00:00 and endDate is 2018-11-13 23:59:59

const startTS = startDate.getTime() / 1000;
const endTS = endDate.getTime() / 1000;

return [startTS, endTS]
}
```

This is all fine and dandy but the problem is, I'm getting the timestamp relative to my computer's timezone. (GMT+9). So my epoch is the 9th hour of 1970-01-01. Which is not what I need. I need the GMT+0 UTC timestamp.

In this scenario, I'd get `1541948400` and `1542121199`, start and end respectively; where I should be getting `1541980800` and `1542153599`.

Tasukete kudasai

Comment: _" I want to convert it to timestamp while ignoring the client computer's current timezone"_  timestamps are timezone agnostic. They reflect the number of seconds (or milliseconds) since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: @Phil I don't know how to properly phrase it but I get a different timestamp on this method, which is a very simple algorithm. When I convert the timestamp that I get in this method, it's always 9 hours ahead of UTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here...

1. Use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to construct timestamps in UTC

   ```
   const startDate = Date.UTC(start[0], start[1] - 1, start[2]) // a timestamp
   const endDate = Date.UTC(end[0], end[1] - 1, end[2], 23, 59, 59) // a timestamp
   ```

   **Note**: `Date.UTC()` produces a timestamp in milliseconds, not a `Date` instance. Since you're able to set the hours, minutes and seconds as above, you no longer need to manipulate those.
2. Use your existing date strings which adhere to the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) as the sole argument to the `Date` constructor.

   This benefits from [this particular nuance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)...

   > Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

   ```
   const startDate = new Date(sparams)
   const endDate = new Date(eparams)
   ```

   [Parsing ISO 8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Browser_compatibility) is supposedly supported in all decent browsers and IE from v9. Since this relies on a particular *"feature"* that may or may not be implemented in a client, there is an element of risk to this method.

---

For your end date, if parsing you can easily append a time and zone portion to the date string rather than manipulate the date object with hour, minute and second values. For example

```
const endDate = new Date(`${eparams}T23:59:59Z`)
```

alternatively, use [`Date.prototype.setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours)...

```
const endDate = new Date(eparams)
endDate.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59)
```

Comment: Are both of this working in IE11? I'd get random problems in IE11 whenever I pass strings in the Date object.

Comment: @AbanaClara from memory, strings in ISO 8601 format work fine in IE

Comment: Okay this seems to be working for my start date object. But for my end date object, I get the same timestamp adjusted for my local time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Phil. But I think `new Date(Date.UTC)` is what works. I get an error on `.getTime()` without that

Comment: @AbanaClara `Date.UTC()` produces a timestamp, not a `Date` instance so you don't need to use `getTime()`

Comment: Oh sh-- really? Thanks for the answer! Amazing

Comment: I would be very hesitant to ever recommend using the built-in parser. Manually parsing ISO dates is 2 lines of code (or 1 if you want to get funky) and for that you get certainty vs. maybe… maybe not…

Comment: @RobG you mean you don't trust `new Date(someISO8601DateString)`? I've certainly been burnt by IE and non-ISO strings but never encountered a problem when the strings are formatted correctly

Comment: @Phil—not in a general web application where the device may be anything. I just think the risk mitigation is trivial. Also, parsing YYYY-MM-DD as UTC often confuses whereas *parseAsLocal()* and *parseAsUTC* make things clearer. ;-)

Comment: @RobG that's a very fair call. Glad I put both examples in then 

Comment: @RobG I'm keen to see that one-liner dealing with the zero-based month ;-)

Comment: @Phil— `new Date(Date.UTC(...('2018-01-01'.split('-').map((x,i)=>x-(i%2)))))`, but any browser that supports rest parameters that will also parse that date as UTC anyway. ;-)

Comment: @RobG ooh, that's better than what I was trying with a regex, but then I was also trying to include the time portion. Very cool trick with the modulus